# No reply when using flush(), session cookies and long execution time

Tags: php, time, session-cookies, outputcache, flush

I could reduce my problem to the following script I put on my server:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-type: text/plain', TRUE);
flush();
sleep(300);?>
```

When I connect to this script using:

```
GET /test.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
```

I get the header back right away as expected:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 03 Nov 2012 20:15:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Fedora)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.17
Set-Cookie: ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3; path=/
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=m7bmvblakkil96rqjq7j8f0f42; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

If I then kill the connection and reconnect using:

```
GET /proxy/test.php HTTP/1.1                
Host: localhost
Cookie: PHPSESSID=knkeaq2ao0cllpcci0rnassqj4
```

I don't get any header back anymore until I restart my webserver.
I would have expected to again retrieve the response header right away.
I have really no idea why I get this behavior. Maybe it's some kind of a bug? Or I'm misunderstanding some behavior.
It would be great if somebody could help me with this as I really don't have a clue what's going on.

Ps:
Im running Apache/2.2.22 with PHP 5.3.17 on fedora 17, but the server packages are out of the fedora 16 repos as I need zend debugger which does not work with the PHP coming with fedora 17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your session is still open in the first request (for 300 seconds) you cannot start using it in the second. It will wait until the first session is closed and written to the file-system before it will attempt to read it for the second request. Because you cannot be sure the first request wants to modify the same session-variables which are already in use by the second request.

You can use `session_write_close()` before the sleep so that the session variables become available immediatly. But then you cannot change any session variables after that.

Comment: Thank you. Guess you are right, is there really no way to use $_SESSION array out of multiple connections?

Comment: I am not sure if you could circumvent this behaviour if you implement your own session-handler, for instance using your database for storage. You could read up on the `session_set_save_handler`-pages.

Comment: Just found out that after session_write_close() I can still read from session variables so I'm saved. As I found out here http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/#comment-423 one can recall session_start() write to the session variable and then call session_write_close() again.

Comment: use `session_write_close()` in any script which will be long-running on the server. It'll write out and save the session data, release the lock on the session file, but still leave $_SESSION available for reading in that script. Note that you WILL get a desynch on session data if any script coming in later modifies the session while this long running script is still active.